# Web開発のポートフォリオ作成手順と学習内容について

Tags: python, html, css, aws, sql

プログラミング初心者です。現在、HTML,CSS,Pythonを学習中で、同時にポートフォリオ作成を進めようと考えています。Webアプリを作成するときには、
フロントエンドでHTML,CSS,Javascript
バックエンドでPython
そして、SQLとAWSを学ぶ必要があると調べた結果わかりました。

しかし、ポートフォリオを作成するさいに、SQLやAWSの知識はどこで必要になるのでしょうか？
学びながら進めたいと考えているのですが、どこで知識が必要になるかわからないので、お助けください。

Comment: 作成されるポートフォリオの用途は何でしょうか？

Comment: 作成理由は２つあり。１つ目は、就活のため。２つ目が、Web開発について学びながら実際に作り深く学びたい。というのが理由です。

Answer (score 2):

[ポートフォリオ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA_(%E6%9B%96%E6%98%A7%E3%81%95%E5%9B%9E%E9%81%BF))が

> - 自己アピールや商品アピールなどのために、主に実績をまとめた資料のこと。特に作家などが就職活動や自己の能力紹介などのために、作品集をまとめたものを指す。

の意味なら、SQLやAWSの知識は必要ありません。既にSQLやAWSの知識を持っているならば、それを紹介すればいいと思います。

Comment: Web開発の必要な知識を学びたいという理由もある場合、SQLとAWSはどの段階で学べばいいでしょうか？

Comment: @Haruki 本サイトは一問一答形式です。ポートフォリオと学習はつながりませんので、本スレッドは解決済みにし、学習について改めて質問してください。

Answer (score 0):

「Web開発について学びながら実際に作り深く学びたい」のであれば、作りたいサービスにクラウドやDBが必要であれば事前にある程度学ぶ必要があるかと思います。そうでなければ必要になったときに学ぶでも良いかと思います。目的なく勉強してもあまり身に付かないかと思います。

「就活のため」のポートフォリオであれば、ご自身のスキルや実績を見せる資料であり今出来ることを形にすれば良いのではないでしょうか。